# PHP regular expression match any character with space tab carriage return and new lines

Tags: php, regex, expression, match

How can i match text that is 10 characters at minimum and 4000 at maximum and that text can be any character. Furthermore i need to accept space tab carriage return and new lines.

I tried:

```
"/.{10,4000}$/"
```

But that didn't work! I think that the dot does not include carriage return for example.

So can anybody help me with this ?

Sorry any misspelling, i am Portuguese.

Comment: Are you avoiding `strlen` for a particular reason?

Comment: nop, that is actually a good question! i thought regex would be more solid ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`s` so `.` matches newlines.

```
"/^.{10,4000}$/s"
```

Comment: You would also want to put a start of string anchor `^` or else you are just matching the last 4k characters and the string could be longer.

Comment: Yes, thought it was in there already :)

Comment: i will aceept this answer because it is more specific to the question, althoug jszobody's answer is more effective

Answer (score 6):

Note that the dot will match *any* character. So why not just do this:

```
if(strlen($text) >= 10 && strlen($text) <= 4000) {
    echo "match!";
}
```

Comment: +1 for not using regex where it isn't needed

Comment: i accepted this AbraCadaver's answer because it is more specific to the question, although your answer is more effective

Answer (score 1):

try this pattern `/^.{10,4000}$/s`
note the "s" modifier and the anchor "^"

Comment: @John Doyle, thanks for your comment, I believe my answer matches the accepted answer by the OP. the accepted answer just happened to be posted while I was editing mine.